# if $n>2$ then continuous curve have volume zero on unit spheres {$\|x\|=1$}

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation

if $n>2$ and the $C^{1}$-curve $\gamma = (\gamma_1, ... , \gamma_n)$,  lies on the sphere $\mid x\mid=1$, (an object of dimension $n-1>1$)  then the $(n-1)-\dim$ volume (area if $n=3$) of its image on the sphere is zero. (Take $n=3$ to fix ideas, and explain why the statement is wrong when $n=2!$) 
Hence the image of gamma can not have interior points (relative to the sphere); in particular, it would be far from a Peano curve!!

How to prove the last statement?    Hint: On a small portion a sphere is practically flat.

This question is the next part of this question [Image of continuously differentiable curve $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ has volume zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490388/image-of-continuously-differentiable-curve-gamma0-1-rightarrow-mathbbrn)
Please if someone can give me an idea to do this. I will be thankful for it.

Comment: What is the connection to complex analysis?

Comment: I am thinking to do it by using approximation theorem to find homotopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each point $p$ on your curve choose a small neighbourhood $B_p$ (on your sphere), such that $B_p$ is contained in a coordinate chart. Now the coordinate version of your curve is inside $B_p$, is a curve $\tilde \gamma_p $ in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. Since $n>2$ you get (from the question your referenced to) that the $n-1$-volume of $\tilde \gamma_p$ is 0. Since this is the case for every point $p$ on your curve the entire volume is 0.

Comment: Dear thanks for giving me hints can you suggest some book to go through these concepts in detail.

Comment: As for the part about smooth manifolds (or surfaces) I'd recommend John M. Lee's book "Smooth Manifolds". For the measure part I'd recommend Walter Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis".